# How can I throw a error if the user enters more than one integer

Tags: c++, validation, input, error-handling, c++17

So this is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

long int iterFunc(int);
long int recurFunc(int);


int main() {
  int n;

   while(true){
      try{
         cout << "Enter: ";
         if (!(cin >> n))
            throw("Type Error");
         if (n < 0)
            throw n;
         else 
            if (n == 0)
             break;
            cout << "Iterative: " << iterFunc(n) << endl;
            cout << "Recursive: " << recurFunc(n) << endl;
      }
      catch(int n){
         cout << "Error. Enter positive number." << endl;
      }
      catch(...){
         cin.clear();
         cin.ignore(100, '\n');
         cout << "Error. Please enter a number" << endl;
      }
   }
   cout << "Goodbye!";
   return 0;
}

long int iterFunc(int n){
  vector<long int> yVec = {1, 1, 1, 3, 5};
  if (n <= 5)
    return yVec[n - 1];
  else
    for(int i = 5;i < n; i++){
      long int result = yVec[i - 1] + 3 * yVec[i- 5];
      yVec.push_back(result);
    }
    return yVec.back();
}

long int recurFunc(int n){
  switch (n) { 
    case 1:  
    case 2:  
    case 3:  
      return 1; 
      break;
    case 4:
      return 3;
      break;
    case 5:
      return 5; 
      break;
    default:  
      return recurFunc(n - 1) + 3 * recurFunc(n - 5); 
      break;   
  } 
}`
```

The program shoud accept only one integer and return the y of the function using both iterative and recursive implemetations. Ex.: 30, 59, 433. How can I throw an error message if the user enters more then one integer, separated by space? Ex.: '3 45 32'.
I tried using `if (cin.getline == ' ') throw("Error name")` but the program still executes and return the y of the function for number in the input

Comment: Read the input as a line via `std::string` and `std::getline`, parse the line via `std::istringstream`, and in the case where you detect more than one input argument, ignore the whole thing, bark the error, and move on. Frankly, your use-case for not wanting to support more than one input argument is a bit weak, but also not well-described, so that may be why.

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but this code is not an appropriate use of exceptions. Just use `if ... else` for the error handling. Exceptions are for errors that can’t be handled locally.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this works:

```
int main()
{
  std::string str;
  std::cout << "? : ";
  std::getline(std::cin, str);
  std::string::size_type pos(0);
  int i = std::stoi(str, &pos);
  if (pos != str.length())
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a part of my old code that might come in handy.

```cpp
int val;
do
{
    cin>>val;
    if(!cin){ //you can add more conditions here
        cin.clear();
        cin.sync();

    /* additional error handling */

    }
    else{
        break; //input is correct - leaving loop
    }
}while(true); //or here
```

Basically what `!cin` does is - it checks what type of value you actually want to write to, because it's needed anyway to figure out if data type is written to the correct type of our `val`. This means, that "30" or "433" etc. are integers (correct), "s" or "string" etc. are strings (or char*, correct me if I am wrong) (incorrect).

This also means, that "3 45 32" **should** be interpreted as string, which **should** result in another loop run.

**Note:** I didn't really test this code, so it might be completely wrong.

**Edit:** Okay now after some tests I realised this code needs some retweaking.

Firstly, "3 45 32" **is not interpreted as string** (now understandable). Instead, first number (before whitespace) is saved as an integer and all other numbers are stored in the buffer (next cin will be filled with it), which we can avoid using `cin.clear()` and `cin.sync()` once again.

The question is - is it okay for you to accept the first integer and ignore everything after the first whitespace? If not, you will have to save the input as  string and extract whatever data you want from it.

I am leaving the original answer as is for simplicity of finding references in this edit.